# Great uploader like uploadify but with a "no-flash" fallback

Tags: jquery, file-upload, mootools, uploadify

Is there a great uploader script that uses jQuery, like uploadify, but with a fallback option for when flash is not available?

I tried [FancyUpload](http://digitarald.de/project/fancyupload/), which has this and uses an invisible IFRAME to do its stuff. The problem is, it's built on top of Mootools (conflicts everywhere because I can't change my whole codebase to use jQuery instead of $ if I use jQuery.noConflict(), and I really don't think it's a good idea to mix js libraries like that).

Comment: Flash fallback or no flash fallback? Your title and question conflict.

Comment: js libriaries are all JavaScript, IMO.

Comment: @Eric You're right, it was not very clear. I edited the title, hope it's better now.

Comment: If you include MooTools >= 1.2.3 after jQuery, it will leave the $ alone.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

http://www.plupload.com/ falls back from HTML5 to Flash, Gears, Silverlight and iFrame. It's developed for TinyMCE, so it's extensively tested and actively developed. One downside could be the size, but simply include it only on the sites that need to upload files and reduce size but excluding Gear or Silverlight support.

I am the author of FancyUpload, so believe me when I approve another uploader ;)

Comment: +1 for your hard work on fancyupload :) if only it used jQuery...

Answer (score 26):

Sebastian Tschan just released a great plugin called jQuery File Upload that will likely suit your needs.

Demo: http://aquantum-demo.appspot.com/file-upload

Repos: https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload

Comment: Just what I was looking for and then some.

Comment: IE<9 does not support multiple file uploads. This uploader has no flash fallback.