# changing the list of allowed files in a file upload window

Tags: javascript, jquery, file-upload, browser

[image]is there a way to change the list of files in the file upload window using js? I know there is another [thread here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14333126/file-upload-changing-the-all-files-in-the-popup-window) talking about that, but it doesn't answer my question as it's using plugins, whereas I'd like to know if it's possible to do it without plugin. In the browser I'm using the accept attribute already so the files displayed when you hit "Browse" are already filtered but I want to change the list of files in the drop down menu and have, in addition to All files, the other files included as values of the accept property. Is this possible with no plugin?
thanks

Comment: by files, do you mean file types or an actual full filename? Also, some of the information in that thread is not accurate any more

Comment: I actually mean modify the list of file types in the drop down menu

Comment: `accept=.abc,.def,.ghi` will (in Firefox at least) default to .abc AND .def AND .ghi, with options for just one of the above or all files - is that what you mean?

Comment: No @Jaromanda, that's not what I meant, I'm already using the accept attribute as I said in my original post. When you click on the Browse button you get a window listing files then a drop down menu on the right side just above the Open button. At the moment is has "Custom files" and "all files", and that's the one I want to change and have a list of files allowed (the same as the ones in the `accepted` attribute). The link to the other thread above shows you exactly what I mean.

Comment: I read that other thread, and I have to admit one of us doesn't know what you are talking about

Comment: Right, so I added an image, hopefully that clarifies it. In the image you can see the popup window that opens up when you try to upload a file. At the bottom right you can see the expanded drop down menu with file types in it, that is the list I want to amend, if possible, with no plugin.