# HTML5 replacement for Uploadify

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, flash

I have been using Uploadify for several years to upload files onto our Intranet web site.  It is no longer actively being supported and even their so called HTML5 version uses a Flash SWF file.  Needless to say, Flash is dead.

I found several really nice Bootstrap / HTML5 uploaders.  I am having trouble picking one I can easily swap with Uploadify.  My site is still running Bootstrap 2 and I want to stay away from CSS3 for this site.  I am not only uploading a file but posting data back to a .NET ASHX handler to create a record in the database.

Can anyone recommend a good, basic replacement?

NOTE:  Dumping me to a question for 6 years ago is not helpful!  I already said I read all of this unhelpful information.

Comment: you don't really need a tool, vanilla has decent upload support these days, what with onprogress, FormData, and URL.createObjectURL() and all...

Comment: This is NOT a duplicate.

Comment: btw, a quick fix for uploadify (to fallback to single file upload is to change flashVer=-1 to flashVer="-1" in its code (else it fails when it reaches flashVer.split)

Answer (score 1):

"http://www.plupload.com/ falls back from HTML5 to Flash, Gears, Silverlight and iFrame. It's developed for TinyMCE, so it's extensively tested and actively developed. One downside could be the size, but simply include it only on the sites that need to upload files and reduce size but excluding Gear or Silverlight support."

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4960718/great-uploader-like-uploadify-but-with-a-no-flash-fallback)

Comment: Plupload is overly complicated for an Intranet site.  I don't need 6 levels of fallback on a page that is already heavy.

Comment: https://github.com/missra-kit/jquery-plugins/tree/master/UploadiFive

Please check this link . It is work for me.